# Right Sidebar links need to appear on top on small screens

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Our layout is divided in 3 main parts, top part has main menu, and below that is main content and page specific sidebar on the right.

The main content and sidebar are separated by bootstrap col-* classes.

When page is displayed on small screen, I need to move the right sidebar above the main content, not below (which is default behavior of bootstrap col). Also need to convert it from '' to '' once it moves to the top. I tried `d-flex` `row-reverse` and `col-reverse` but that didn't change anything.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <main role="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row d-flex">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8">
                    this is the main content. this is the main content.this is the main content. <br />
                    this is the main content. this is the main content.this is the main content. <br />
                    this is the main content. this is the main content.this is the main content. <br />
                    this is the main content. this is the main content.this is the main content. <br />
                    this is the main content. this is the main content.this is the main content. <br />
                    this is the main content. this is the main content.this is the main content. <br />
                    this is the main content. this is the main content.this is the main content. <br />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                    <h3>Sidebar</h3>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Sidebar Link 1</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Sidebar Link 2</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Sidebar Link 3</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Sidebar Link 4</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Sidebar Link 5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Comment: Do you want the sidebar to move to top on screens whose length are less than 576px or above? By applying (sm) you apply styling towards the screens greater than 576px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap offers a clean and easy way to achieve this using column ordering. Here is the link to [official documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/columns/#order-classes) for bootstrap 5. Basically the columns will be ordered from 1-6.

Remember that bootstrap is mobile first. We apply `order-1` to make the sidebar appear before main content on devices with screen resolution below 576px. Then we apply `order-md-2` to make the sidebar appear after the main content on screen resolutions beyond 768px.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<main role="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row d-flex">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 order-2 order-md-1">
        this is the main content. this is the main content.this is the main content. <br /> this is the main content. this is the main content.this is the main content. <br /> this is the main content. this is the main content.this is the main content.
        <br /> this is the main content. this is the main content.this is the main content. <br /> this is the main content. this is the main content.this is the main content. <br /> this is the main content. this is the main content.this is the main
        content. <br /> this is the main content. this is the main content.this is the main content. <br />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 order-1 order-md-2">
        <h3>Sidebar</h3>
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Sidebar Link 1</a></li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Sidebar Link 2</a></li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Sidebar Link 3</a></li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Sidebar Link 4</a></li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Sidebar Link 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed the [class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/#enable-flex-behaviors) `row` by `flex-column-reverse`

We have the expected behavior, the sidebar above the main content.

After you can use [media query](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/#media-queries) to set in function of the screen size.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <main role="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column-reverse">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8">
                    this is the main content. this is the main content.this is the main content. <br />
                    this is the main content. this is the main content.this is the main content. <br />
                    this is the main content. this is the main content.this is the main content. <br />
                    this is the main content. this is the main content.this is the main content. <br />
                    this is the main content. this is the main content.this is the main content. <br />
                    this is the main content. this is the main content.this is the main content. <br />
                    this is the main content. this is the main content.this is the main content. <br />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                    <h3>Sidebar</h3>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Sidebar Link 1</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Sidebar Link 2</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Sidebar Link 3</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Sidebar Link 4</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Sidebar Link 5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Comment: Adding the class `flex-md-column` after the `flex-column-reverse` would make it the complete answer.